# Regex - how to get a matched string excluding all groups?

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to use regex to filter out all parts of a string, enclosed in brackets.

For instance, having input:
`data1 data2[comment] data3[comment] data4 data5[comment][comment]`
I want to get:
`data1 data2 data3 data4 data5`

Is it possible to achieve it with regex?

Comment: No, only single pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regex to match everying that's enclosed within brackets (including square brackets):

```
(\[[^\]]*\])
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/7HLQkK/1

Java example:

```
String string = "data1 data2[comment] data3[comment] data4 data5[comment][comment]";
string = string.replaceAll("(\\[[^\\]]*\\])", "");
```

and javascript:

```js
var string = "data1 data2[comment] data3[comment] data4 data5[comment][comment]";
string = string.replace(/(\[[^\]]*\])/g, "");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Replace! Didn't think about this one.